# Expressing Elliptic functions as ratio of $\wp$ and $\wp'$

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

I was reading Stein's book on Complex analysis, and on page 271 they say that every elliptic function $f$ with periods 1, and $\tau$ is a ratio of $\wp$ and $\wp'$. The book doesn't have a proof of this theorem, but it says that this theorem above will be an easy consequence of the following version of it:  "Every even elliptic function $F$ with periods 1, $\tau$ is a rational function of $\wp$."

I'm not sure how to get the odd elliptic functions from this: but I think with is that it will maybe be a product of $\wp'$ and some rational function of $\wp$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It's how do you develop _odd_ elliptic functions from a theorem that states how _even_ elliptic functions can be developed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be an elliptic function.
As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3485279/a-result-related-to-elliptic-functions), there exist rational functions $R_1$ and $R_2$ such, for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, we have $$f(z)=R_1[\wp(z)] + \wp'(z) R_2[\wp(z)].$$

Since both summands are (multivariate) rational functions of $\wp$ and $\wp'$, by expanding fractions, one sees that so is $f$.