# A result related to elliptic functions

Tags: analytic-number-theory, elliptic-functions

I am  trying exercises in elliptic functions from Tom M Apostol and I am unable to think about this problem.

> Problem is --> Prove that every elliptic function for can be expressed in the form for(z) = $R_1[\wp(z) ] $ + $ \wp'(z) R_2[\wp(z) ] $ , where $R_1$ and $ R_2$ are rational functions and $\wp $ has same set of periods as f.

I thought that as $\wp(z) $ is even so it's derivative would be odd function and every function can be written as combination of odd and even functions. Also, every even elliptic function is a rational function of $\wp(z) $ is a known result.

But I am not clear how to use all these results to prove this and whether these results are sufficient to prove this. 
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just separating a function into its odd an even parts. If $f$ is elliptic
then
$$f(z)=\frac{f(z)+f(-z)}{2}+\frac{f(z)-f(-z)}{2}$$
is the sum of an even and odd elliptic function. The even part is a rational
function of $\wp(z)$. Dividing the odd part by $\wp'(z)$ gives an even elliptic
function which is also a rational function of $\wp(z)$. So the odd part has
the form $\wp'(z)R_2(\wp(z))$ where $R_2$ is a rational function.